# .htaccess deny/allow rules denying folder, but not direct to files

Tags: apache-2.2, security, .htaccess

We have a .htaccess file in a folder configured with deny,allow as follows:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from <whitelist IP>
Allow from <whitelist IP>
....
```

There are no other rewrite etc. rules in this file, just the deny/allow stuff.

If you attempt to go to http://www.xyz.site/protected/ (no filename) from a denied IP, you get the Forbidden error as expected. If, however, you go to http://www.xyz.site/protected/filename.php - where filename.php is a valid file inside the folder, e.g. the login form, the page loads - but with no images or CSS (presumably still denied per the .htaccess)

Why isn't this .htaccess setup preventing access to the whole folder from denied IPs - might there be a conflicting server permission somewhere overriding it?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your configuration. How is the php interpreter invoked? You are using it via CGI, FastCGI or are you using the embedded php interpreter, aka mod_php?

Comment: FastCGI. We've got a .htaccess file in the parent folder to our protected one which contains a line to stop RewriteRules taking effect in the folder:

    RewriteRule ^protected/(.*) - [L]

Could this be interfering with the deny/allow logic?

I'm also risking the wrath of the mods by mentioning this, I suspect, but the server is also running Plesk 10.4.4.....

Comment: Then probably apache is configured to forward all the .php requests to the fastgci interpreter before parsing the .htaccess file...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that .htaccess content is not being interpreted and the "Forbidden" result on accessing the directory comes from forbidden DirectoryListings (non-existing index-file?).